# rendering shared js erb template in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb, ujs

I'm trying to render a shared javascript template in Rails 3.

I have two controller actions, both named update.

For each controller action i have a `update.js.erb' file, i want it to look like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/_update.js.erb' >
```

Or even nicer:

```
<%= render 'shared/update' %>
```

But when i do this i get parsing errors around my erb elements, something like:

`/Users/ipd/Projects/master/app/views/shared/_update.js.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
'); when Activity::Rating`

What is the proper way to render js templates?

thanks!

**UPDATE:** i solved the case syntax error problem by removing the extra whitespace in the template.  There were spaces between each `<% when :case %>` line.  (!!!)

But, i'm still not able to get the js to execute when using a partial.

Comment: Can you paste the code from the partial? Why did you decide to use ujs? It's slow, it's messy, it's very hard to debug. It's much better to separate javascript code from templates.

Comment: why UJS?  It seemed like the thing to do at the time.  Having more experience now, I think I agree, UJS is messy and hard to debug.